# Generate invoice "against" or "for" a sale order?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

I am little confused about the words 'against' and 'for'. Please help me to select the correct statement from the two below:

> 1. Generate invoice **against** a sale order.
> 2. Generate invoice **for** a sale order.

Comment: Probably something like this: #1: you pull up the order, bring a blank invoice next to (i.e. against) it, and fill it in; #2: you look at the order and make an invoice to suit. The terms carry over to electronic invoicing even if the physical actions don't.

Comment: There is no need to use against. It's overly accounting oriented. To make payment against an invoice, sure. Generate an invoice for a sale order.

Comment: @WS2 In the States, we "cut checks", not invoices. I repeat: *generate an invoice against a sale order* is not great. The word "against" refers to columns in bookkeeping. For example, column A has the orders and column B has the payment or payment orders. So, if you use "against", you should be aware of that. Just saying [40 years of translating bookkeeping and accounting documents] :)

Comment: @Lambie You are right that the word "against" can be used for many things - including "the photocopier is against the window". I might well have spoken of raising an invoice "for" a shipment - but "against" seems to work for me. I've been out of it all for several years now! This all reminds me of the joke cracked at many an Accountants annual dinner - about the debit side being the one nearer the window, and the credit nearer the door.

Comment: @WS2  Why is it that you can acknowledge what I say about "against" in bookkeeping? I don't get it. Yes, credit near the door, debit near the window. That's funny.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not altogether clear what you are saying about "against". Your point about the columns seems to use "against" in its physical sense. *The payment column is against the invoice column* is like *she sits against the window*. But when I raise an invoive  against a shipment, I am using an entirely different sense of "against". It is OED sense 7b *In exchange for, in return for; as an equivalent or set-off for; in lieu of, instead of. * e.g *A voucher redeemable against services*

Comment: WS2 In accounting, there did not use to be any computers. So, yes, against is physical in the sense of **entered in the accounts under a column. You raise an invoice against a shipment is the same thing. Column A are the shipments (outgoing, for example), Column B are the invoices entered for them. The items in Column A are now listed **against** the items in Column B. The OED coheres with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is technically correct.  One definition of 'against' is 'compared or contrasted with'.

"Company X owes us money and has several open orders.  Generate an invoice against a sale order.  We will collect piecemeal."

There are several other definitions of 'against' that depending upon the context of the sentence would make sense too.

All that said, 'for' (along with the missing articles) is a more common phrasing in American English.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against

Comment: This answer shows you that 'against' can mean opposing as in fighting, or it can mean opposing as in facing (Put the seating on the two opposing walls, up against the windows.)

Comment: You can also "lean on" or "lean against" something, with similar meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Personally (with 40 yrs accountancy experience) I would probably "raise an invoice against...". But then one doesn't usually do it against the order. If one is dealing with the sale of goods, the invoice wouldn't be raised until they were shipped, which could be anything from a short time to a very long time after receiving the order. However I see nothing wrong with raising an invoice either "for" a shipment, or "against" a shipment.

There is also nothing wrong with saying "generate" - it is just that I normally say "raise". In some offices (usually American), they "cut" invoices.

Every company will have its own system of doing this. But nowadays computerised documents of this kind are all linked in some way.

Comment: I think self-authentication is acceptable here.